# HTTP POST with Wininet API on Delphi

Tags: java, json, delphi, http, wininet

I'm using Delphi 2010 for sending an HTTP request to a Java application. Specifically, I'm sending a JSON object. But, when sending the request, I don't know what's happening, but the object is not correct.

I send the object like this:

```
{"entidad":"1","username":"A","password":"1234"}
```

My sniffer reads the object like this:

```
%�7�B�%�2�2�e�n�t�i�d�a�d�%�2�2�%�3�A�%�2�2�8�3�0�0�2�3�0�0�0�%�2�2�%�2�C�
```

Therefore, my Java application doesn't read the object and it's causing a null pointer exception.

My code is here:

```
function TFormMain.JSONPostRequest(Server,Url,jo : String; blnSSL: Boolean): String;
var
  aBuffer     : Array[0..4096] of Char;
  Header      : TStringStream;
  BufStream   : TMemoryStream;
  BytesRead   : Cardinal;
  pSession    : HINTERNET;
  pConnection : HINTERNET;
  pRequest    : HINTERNET;
  port        : Integer;
  flags       : DWord;
begin
  Result := '';
  pSession := InternetOpen(nil, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if Assigned(pSession) then
  try
    if blnSSL then
      Port := INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT
    else
      Port := 9000;
    pConnection := InternetConnect(pSession, PChar(Server), port, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
    if Assigned(pConnection) then
    try
      if blnSSL then
        flags := INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE or INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION
      else
        flags := INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP;
      pRequest := HTTPOpenRequest(pConnection, 'POST', PChar(Url), nil, nil, nil, flags, 0);
      if Assigned(pRequest) then
      try
        Header := TStringStream.Create('');
        try
          with Header do
          begin
            WriteString('Host: ' + Server + ':' + IntToStr(Port) + sLineBreak);
          end;
          HttpAddRequestHeaders(pRequest, PChar(Header.DataString), Length(Header.DataString), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
          if HTTPSendRequest(pRequest, nil, 0, Pointer(jo), Length(jo)) then
          begin
            BufStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
            try
              while InternetReadFile(pRequest, @aBuffer, SizeOf(aBuffer), BytesRead) do
              begin
                if (BytesRead = 0) then Break;
                BufStream.Write(aBuffer, BytesRead);
              end;
              aBuffer[0] := #0;
              BufStream.Write(aBuffer, 1);
              Result := WideCharToString(PChar(BufStream.Memory));
            finally
              BufStream.Free;
            end;
          end
          else
            raise Exception.Create('HttpOpenRequest failed. ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
        finally
          Header.Free;
        end;
      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(pRequest);
      end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(pConnection);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(pSession);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My sniffer reads the object like this:
>
> ```
> %�7�B�%�2�2�e�n�t�i�d�a�d�%�2�2�%�3�A�%�2�2�8�3�0�0�2�3�0�0�0�%�2�2�%�2�C�
> ```

Your JSON data is encoded in UTF-16, because `string` is an alias for `UnicodeString` in Delphi 2010.  You are sending the raw bytes of that string as-is instead of encoding them to UTF-8, which is JSON's default charset.  As mjn said, you are misusing `HttpSendRequest()` in that regard.

Also, your input JSON string appears to have been url-encoded before being passed to `JSONPostRequest()` (`HTTPSendRequest()` does not url-encode raw data).  Don't url-encode the JSON, pass the original JSON as-is.

Also, `INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP` is not a valid flag for `HTTPOpenRequest()`.

You did not show the code that is calling `JSONPostRequest()`, so I can't show you how to fix the url-encoding issue.  But try something more like this for the actual post:

```pascal
function WinInetErrorMsg(Err: DWORD): string;
var
  ErrMsg: array of Char;
  ErrLen: DWORD;
begin
  if Err = ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR then
  begin
    ErrLen := 0;
    InternetGetLastResponseInfo(Err, nil, ErrLen);
    if GetLastError() = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then
    begin
      SetLength(ErMsg, ErrLen);
      InternetGetLastResponseInfo(Err, PChar(ErMsg), ErrLen);
      SetString(Result, PChar(ErrMsg), ErrLen);
    end else begin
      Result := 'Unknown WinInet error';
    end;
  end else
    Result := SysErrorMessage(Err);
end;

function TFormMain.JSONPostRequest(const Server, Url: string; const jo : UTF8String; blnSSL: Boolean): String;
var
  aBuffer     : Array of Byte;
  Header      : String;
  BufStream   : TStringStream;
  BytesRead   : DWORD;
  pSession    : HINTERNET;
  pConnection : HINTERNET;
  pRequest    : HINTERNET;
  port        : Integer;
  flags       : DWORD;
begin
  Result := '';
  pSession := InternetOpen(nil, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if not Assigned(pSession) then
    raise Exception.Create('InternetOpen failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));
  try
    if blnSSL then
      Port := INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT
    else
      Port := 9000;
    pConnection := InternetConnect(pSession, PChar(Server), port, nil, nil, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
    if not Assigned(pConnection) then
      raise Exception.Create('InternetConnect failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));
    try
      if blnSSL then
        flags := INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE
      else
        flags := 0;
      pRequest := HTTPOpenRequest(pConnection, 'POST', PChar(Url), nil, nil, nil, flags, 0);
      if not Assigned(pRequest) then
        raise Exception.Create('HttpOpenRequest failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));
      try
        Header := 'Host: ' + Server + ':' + IntToStr(Port) + #13#10 +
                  'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8'#13#10;

        if not HttpAddRequestHeaders(pRequest, PChar(Header), Length(Header), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD) then
          raise Exception.Create('HttpAddRequestHeaders failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));

        if not HTTPSendRequest(pRequest, nil, 0, PAnsiChar(jo), Length(jo)) then
          raise Exception.Create('HTTPSendRequest failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));

        SetLength(aBuffer, 4096);
        BufStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.Default);
        try
          repeat
            if not InternetReadFile(pRequest, PByte(aBuffer), Length(aBuffer), BytesRead) then
              raise Exception.Create('InternetReadFile failed. ' + WinInetErrorMsg(GetLastError));
            if (BytesRead = 0) then Break;
            BufStream.WriteBuffer(PByte(aBuffer)^, BytesRead);
          until False;
          Result := BufStream.DataString;
        finally
          BufStream.Free;
        end;
      finally
        InternetCloseHandle(pRequest);
      end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(pConnection);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(pSession);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, Remy. This code helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: @FelipeCeballos-Desystec Then you can accept it as an answer by clicking on the checkmark under this post, on the left.

Answer (score 2):

JSON uses UTF-8 by default, Delphi (2009 and newer) uses UTF-16 as default encoding. Your code needs to convert the JSON to a UTF-8 string before passing it to HTTPSendRequest.

I would also add a request header to indicate the encoding, so that the Java side knows that it is UTF-8.

Comment: Agreed.  the last parameters of `HTTPSendRequest()` expect **raw bytes**, not **string characters**.  Also, the use of `WideCharToString(PChar(BufStream.Memory));` is very suspicious, because `PChar()` is `PWideChar` in D2010 and HTTP response data is usually NOT encoded as UTF-16.